# how to concat two string resource in xml textview without binding

Tags: android

Let's say i have a info like

> android:hint="Event*"

I'm trying to internationalize my app. So, I have 10 languages and in all language Event is translated
So i'll put it on string resource and use it like

> android:hint="@string/event"

Now, I just want to use this Event in same way sometimes and in some cases I need to append it with some special character's like * ! @ $ etc.

I don't want it to set from java file nor i like to use data binding i.e {{ }}
in direct xml is there any way to concat string like

> android:hint="@string/event + *"
>
> android:hint="@string/event + !"
>
> android:hint="@string/event + %"

if not i need to feature request android team. how to request them ?

Comment: Do it programmatically.Like

youredittext.setHint("");

Comment: @ParthLotia This is very old project and already it's done if i want to change programatically i need to mess with their code. it's complicated there are at least 1000 strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is possible to be done statically.

But, a little search gave me this library [LikeTheSalad](https://github.com/LikeTheSalad/android-string-reference)

Extract of the README :

It allows you to do something like this:

```
<string name="app_name">world</string>
<string name="template_welcome_message">hello ${app_name}</string>
```

And then the library does this at build time:

```
<string name="welcome_message">hello world</string>
```